# wxpython event handling: GetValue after key is pressed

Tags: python, event-handling, wxpython, wxwidgets

I want to get the value of a TextCtrl every time this TextCtrl gets changed. My code returns me the "old" value (like before I pressed the key) - but I want to get the "new" value with the key I pressed. 
For example, when the Value of my TC is "123" and I add a "4", I still get "123" returned, but I want to get "1234".

```
class pageThree(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent,size=(800,600))
        self.pageThree=wx.Panel(self,size=(800,600))    
        self.TC = wx.TextCtrl(self.pageThree,-1,pos=(100,150),size=(60,20))
        self.TC.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.getValue)

    def getValue(self, event):
        print self.TC.GetValue()
```

As I only work with integers in this TC, I tried to add **+ event.GetKeyCode() - 48**, but this does not work when I delete a value instead of adding one =/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind to wx.EVT_TEXT instead of wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN. See the following example:

```
import wx

########################################################################
class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        self.text = wx.TextCtrl(self)
        self.text.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT, self.onText)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onText(self, event):
        """
        """
        print self.text.GetValue()


########################################################################
class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Events!")
        panel = MyPanel(self)
        self.Show()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```